# Formatting raw string in Python when using exact match regex

Tags: python, regex, string-formatting

The `fr` prefix can combine `f` and `r` flag.
But when it comes to the regex's exact match, it seems that it can't format the raw string well:

```py
import re

RE1 = r'123'
RE2 = re.compile(fr'@{3} {RE1}')
```

Then, the `RE2.pattern` will become `'@3 123'`,

but what I want is `'@{3} 123'`.

Comment: What is your intended meaning for `@{3}`?  Is the `3` a placeholder, or is this literal text?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the `@{3}` means exact match `@` 3 times here, `3` is not a placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the braces surrounding the `3` like this, otherwise they will be interpreted as string interpolation:

```
import re

RE1 = r'123'
RE2 = re.compile(fr'@{{3}} {RE1}')
print(RE2)
```

This produces:

```
@{3} 123
```

Ref: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

> Note that the correct way to have a literal brace appear in the
>   resulting string value is to double the brace:
>
> ```
> >>> f'{{ {4*10} }}'
> '{ 40 }'
> >>> f'{{{4*10}}}'
> '{40}'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> RE2 = re.compile(r'@{3} '+RE1)

Works for me, observe:

> RE2.pattern

'@{3} 123'

Hope that helps.